# Can a toilet fill valve be properly installed entirely under the water line?

Tags: toilet

Most instructions I've found online and in books say that a toilet fill valve will have a Critical Level marker on it indicating that the top of the overflow tube should be 1" below it.  In one of my toilets I have a fill valve which is entirely submerged in the water, thus definitely not 1" above the outflow tube.  Is it possible that this is a correct installation or are there no exceptions to this rule?  There is a "Hoov-R-Line" brand name on the device but I can't find any documentation online.

[image: Toilet tank]

Comment: It shouldn't be completely submerged; there should be an air gap to ensure against backflow.

Comment: Thanks, replaced the fill valve with an adjustable one and set it to the correct height.